# JSON: UnrecognizedPropertyException for List of child objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

It seems to be a straightforward implementation but somehow not working for me.

```
public class ParentEntity {

   private List<ChildEntity> childFields;

   public List<ChildEntity> getChildFields() {
      return childFields;
   }

   public void setChildFields(List<ChildEntity> childFields) {
     this.childFields = childFields;
   }

}
```

**Input JSON**

```
{
 "childFields": [
     {<different child properties>},
     {<different child properties>}
  ]
}
```

**Exception**

```
class ChildEntity not marked as ignorable (11 known properties:...different child field properties
```

Comment: Looks correct to me, can you share your code where you read your JSON?

Comment: `private List<ChildEntity> childFields = new ArrayList<>();`?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the exception message that you added, you have a mismatch in the properties you specified in your JSON for the ChildEntity and the ChildEntity properties.

If you have a mismatch and you want to specify more properties in JSON, than available in the ChildEntity class, you can use Jackson's

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
```

annotation. It will ignore every property you haven't defined in your POJO.

You could also choose to use:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

It will ignore all the properties that are not declared.